# GPT partition table is corrupt after every one to three reboots

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, gpt, gdisk

After 2 or three power cycles, I get the grub rescue menu. I use a Ubuntu LiveCD to check my drive status and gparted says that my drive don't have any partitions. I checked the internet and I found a tool called gdisk. After using gdisk I got:

```
Caution: invalid backup GPT header, but valid main header; regenerating 
backup header from main header.

Caution! After loading partitions, the CRC doesn't check out!
Warning! Main and backup partition tables differ! Use the 'c' and 'e' options
on the recovery & transformation menu to examine the two tables.

Warning! One or more CRCs don't match. You should repair the disk!

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: damaged

****************************************************************************
Caution: Found protective or hybrid MBR and corrupt GPT. Using GPT, but disk
verification and recovery are STRONGLY recommended.
****************************************************************************

Warning! Secondary partition table overlaps the last partition by
16637841297300849166 blocks!
You will need to delete this partition or resize it in another utility.
```

I checked my partition table and I found that I have 4 new partitions that I didn't create.
I removed them Saved my partition table and then i was able to use my pc.
The problem is I get this error almost every time I shut down or reboot my pc.
I don't know the reason behind it.

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and windows 8.1 in dual boot. My pc is lenovo ideapad z510.
 If you need any report or want me to try a command I will gladly do it. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Sometimes my pc just crushes and I loses my table partition.

I did a test using :

```
smartctl --all /dev/sda
```

And This is the output: http://pastebin.com/VHfVnFU4

Comment: Have you run any disk diagnostics like SMART tests or the appropriate version of fsck? This could be a hardware issue. Do you have another hard drive you can experiment with to see if the problem is the original drive?

Comment: I did a SMART using Lenovo Storage Test inside windows and it passed without detecting any problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the author reinstalled Windows and is unable to replicate the original problem.

Comment: @Ramhound yes go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

This caught my eye in your SMART output:

```
184 End-to-End_Error     0x0032   001   001   099    Old_age   Always   FAILING_NOW 239
```

There are also a bunch of specific errors logged (49 of them, to be precise). I'm not an expert on SMART result interpretation, but from what I do know, I'd be wary of that drive. It's entirely possible that the end-to-end errors are causing the symptoms you're seeing. If so, replacing the disk should fix the problem.

This sort of symptom can also occur because of motherboard-based software RAID (aka "fake RAID") that's activated in the firmware but not being used by the OS, or that's being used in one OS but not another one. In this scenario, the firmware's RAID tools write data to the end of the disk, expecting that the OS will use the disk in the same way and present the disk as slightly smaller than it is to everything else (including tools like `gdisk`). If this is the cause of the problem, you'll have to either track down the RAID settings in your motherboard's firmware and disable them; or activate the relevant RAID support in both Ubuntu and Windows. The latter course of action may require shrinking your final partition, too. Note that these RAID options can be enabled even on a single-disk computer, even though they do no good whatsoever in that configuration.

Answer (score -1):

I reinstalled windows and the problem seems to be gone. I don't understand the cause or reason formatting fixed the problem.